# Getting "The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed." error while debugging on long-working web page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-authorization

Here's the short version of how I'm getting this error.  Our company has a tool written in Aspx which is pretty barebones and used for handheld scanner devices.  This page, when loaded detects to see if a user has logged on, if not, it prompts them to login, then it asks them to make a selection from a drop-down to specify their location and then it loads the main application menu.

For a long time, I've been able to run this application on my machine in debug mode.  However, I'm getting a new error.  When I run the application, I am prompted to login.  I can login successfully and get to the location selector.  On the next step, I can select my location from a drop-down and click continue.

On the back-end, there is a a redirect that takes you to home.aspx.  Home.aspx is a blank page with a Menu user control.  Both the Home page and the menu are super basic.  I have put break points in both Page_Load methods and they execute entirely.  After the home page and menu have loaded, something is breaking internally and I'm getting this error:

> [SystemException: The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed.
> ]
> System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.TranslateToSids(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceAccounts, Boolean& someFailed) +1271
> System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceAccounts, Type targetType, Boolean& someFailed) +46
> System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceAccounts, Type targetType, Boolean forceSuccess) +43
> System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole(String role) +135
> System.Web.SiteMapProvider.IsAccessibleToUser(HttpContext context, SiteMapNode node) +193
> System.Web.SiteMapNode.IsAccessibleToUser(HttpContext context) +18
> System.Web.StaticSiteMapProvider.GetChildNodes(SiteMapNode node) +260
> System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider.GetChildNodes(SiteMapNode node) +29
> System.Web.SiteMapNode.get_ChildNodes() +27
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.SiteMapDataSource.GetNodes(SiteMapNode node) +57
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.SiteMapDataSource.GetNodes() +347
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.SiteMapDataSource.GetTreeView(String viewPath) +37
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.SiteMapDataSource.GetHierarchicalView(String viewPath) +34
> System.Web.UI.HierarchicalDataSourceControl.System.Web.UI.IHierarchicalDataSource.GetHierarchicalView(String viewPath) +11
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.HierarchicalDataBoundControl.GetData(String viewPath) +26
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu.DataBindItem(MenuItem item) +50
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu.PerformDataBinding() +129
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.HierarchicalDataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +111
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +76
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu.DataBind() +10
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +114
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu.EnsureDataBound() +35
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu.CreateChildControls() +109
> System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +97
> System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
> System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +163
> System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +163
> System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +163
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +906

I have turned on in VS that is should break on all exceptions.  It's not breaking on any call in my code and, in fact, it doesn't break on any exception.  It just throws up this error in the browser.

I've tried Googling this error, but nothing seems to work.  We use Web Auth with roles, so I'm not sure what's happening.  My local machine (or my personal user account) is what's used to call Db calls, but I've had no trouble with that in the past.  In fact, within SSMS, I can execute any SQL code I want from within our Dbs, so this isn't a database issue.

Any clue what could cause this?  I know you guys like to see code, but in this context, this doesn't have anything to with my code.  There is a binding method for the menu, however, I've put a breakpoint at the earliest point in that method.  This is the method (within my code) that should execute next after the Page_Load call.  That breakpoint never gets hit before I receive this error.  I have no clue what's going on.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I awoke this morning to try running `gpupdate /force` to see if that would help at all.  I have no clue what changed, but it seems to have fixed the problem.